# GAE container terminated by container manager

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, containers, gcloud

I have an Google App Engine app which is basically a couple NodeJS scripts that run a website.

Some of this scripts are being terminated for apparently no reason, but looking at the logs this is happening:

**Msg1**: Container terminated by the container manager on signal 9.

**Msg2**: Container called exit(1).

[Log image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VXpwd.jpg)

Its quite erratic, seems to only happen during the day, sometimes every 30 secs or so.

Tried googling it but cant find anything like "varlog/system" to find out more on the error, neither that or the error message.

Also already add

```
resources:
  cpu: 2
  memory_gb: 2
```

to the app.yaml to discard any OOM issues.

Anybody saw this or have any idea what could it be?

Comment: Did u find the answer to this?

Comment: Hi Abishnek, it was a problem of my app. Because how it was made, it creted a new instance every time someone opened a connection. Managed this by specifying :

`manual_scaling:
  instances: 1`

in the app.yalm.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

The symptom was my deployment of a simple Standard AppEngine app not completing the creation of a new version.  Like you I found the "Container called exit(1)." error after going into logging for AppEngine and checking "on" all of the log options.  This is related to this issue: [Appengine stuck on "Updating service [default]..."](https://serverfault.com/questions/778213/appengine-stuck-on-updating-service-default)

In my case I found that running "gcloud init" to reset my credentials helped.  Hope this helps someone else.